# How to ask permissions firstly open application in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have making an application in Swift, and I use location, pictures... But this ask the permissions when I open the view of location and when I open the other views. And I want ask all permissions at the first time..

How can I ask all the permissions when I open app first time? Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but is generally considered not best practice so it's not done as often as it used to be. Asking/setting permissions on first start w/o explanation or context or a chance to use the app can be a bad user experience and may cause more users to say "No" and not give those permissions. Then your app won't work as expected. You could include a 'pre-permission' view explaining what's required & why (how does it benefit the user and why does the app need it), then if they click "yes" to that you display the system Permissions. Asking only when the feature is first needed is better

Answer (score 2):

> How can I ask all the permissions when I open app first time? Is this possible?

iOS will present the permission dialog when you start using location services. If you want to make sure that dialog comes up when the app is launched instead of when the user navigates to some view, just start using location services when the app starts up. For example, you could call CLLocationManager's `-startUpdatingLocation` method when the app starts. I don't think that's a great idea -- the user shouldn't have to give permission until the app actually needs the location, and starting location updates early will use power unnecessarily -- but it should accomplish what you're asking for.